# Refactoring websocket wrapper for testability and readability

Tags: c#, websocket, integration-testing

I've implemented a websocket wrapper around [this library](https://github.com/Marfusios/websocket-client) for a 3rd party API integration. The client manages logins, logouts, sends requests, and awaits corresponding responses. Responses can be matched to their initiating requests either by type or a request/response id. If a response isn't received within a specified timeout, that request is considered failed.

Though the code functions as intended, I'm facing challenges in creating integration tests. I want integration tests because the API has a test endpoint and test users that I could use.

The code works fine, however I'm having difficulty in creating integration tests. The 3rd party API provides a test endpoint along with test users, making integration tests an attractive and feasible option. However, my current design seems hard to test.

I aim to test the following behaviors:

1. Logon

   - Execute one at a time. Subsequent calls should wait until the preceding ones are complete.
   - Prevent login attempts if the client is either logging in or is already logged in.
   - Prevent multiple logins on a single websocket connection.
2. logoff

   - Ensure logoffs can't be executed if the client is not logged in.
   - If the client is in the process of logging in, it should complete before logging off.
   - Prevent any API calls post logoff.

The client's state can transition between LoggedOff, LoggingIn, and LoggedIn. To manage these states and logon attempts, I've leveraged BehaviorSubject and ReplaySubject, the former one to inform any new listeners of this state immediately upon subscription, and the latter one because we need to know a sequence of past events or states, not just the latest.

My question: How can I rearchitect or refactor this code to ensure the behaviors listed above, enhance readability, and most importantly, make it conducive to integration testing?

```cs
public enum LogonState
{
    LoggedOff,
    LoggingIn,
    LoggedIn
}

public sealed class WebSocketService : IHostedService, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly TimeSpan _requestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
    private readonly IOptions<Settings> _settings;
    private readonly WebSocketCommunicator _client;
    private readonly CqgApi _api;
    private readonly PendingRequestManager _pendingRequestsManager = new();

    private long _lastRequestId;
    private IDisposable? _mainSubscription;

    private readonly BehaviorSubject<LogonState> _loginStateSubject = new(LogonState.LoggedOff);
    private readonly ReplaySubject<(Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)> _loginAttemptSubject = new();

    public WebSocketService(ILogger<WebSocketService> logger, IOptions<Settings> settings)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(settings.Value);

        _settings = settings;

        _client = new WebSocketCommunicator(new(settings.Value.HostName), settings.Value.Timeout, DisconnectActionAsync, ReconnectActionAsync);
        _api = new CqgApi(this);

        _loginAttemptSubject
            .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .SubscribeAsync(InternalLogonAsync);
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _mainSubscription?.Dispose();

        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public long GetNextRequestId() => Interlocked.Increment(ref _lastRequestId);

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _mainSubscription = _client.MessageReceived
            .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .SubscribeAsync(ProcessServerResponse);

        await _client.Start();
    }

    public async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await _api.LogoffAsync(_ => ValueTask.CompletedTask, _ => ValueTask.CompletedTask);

        await _client.Stop(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "client is closed");
    }

    public void Send<T>(IMessage<T> clientMessage) where T : IMessage<ClientMsg>, IMessage<T>
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(clientMessage);

        if (_loginStateSubject.Value == LogonState.LoggedOff)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("Attempt to send a message in LoggedOff state. Aborted.");
            return;
        }

        byte[] serverMessageRaw;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            clientMessage.WriteTo(memoryStream);
            serverMessageRaw = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        _client.Send(serverMessageRaw);
    }

    public Task RequestAsync(ClientMsg request, Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        _pendingRequestsManager.Add(request, onSuccess, onError, _requestTimeout);
        Send(request);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task InternalLogonAsync((Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError) callbacks)
    {
        var (onSuccess, onError) = callbacks;

        var state = _loginStateSubject.Value;
        switch (state)
        {
            case LogonState.LoggedIn:
                await onError("Already logged in");
                break;

            case LogonState.LoggingIn:
                await onError("Already logging in");
                break;

            case LogonState.LoggedOff:
                _loginStateSubject.OnNext(LogonState.LoggingIn);

                await _api.LogonAsync(_settings.Value.Cqg.UserName, _settings.Value.Cqg.Password, _settings.Value.Cqg.PrivateLabel, _settings.Value.Cqg.ClientAppId,
                    _settings.Value.Cqg.ClientAppVersion, onSuccess, onError);

                break;
        }
    }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        _loginAttemptSubject.OnNext((onSuccess, onError));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ProcessServerResponse(ResponseMessage responseMessage)
    {
        var serverMsg = ServerMsg.Parser.ParseFrom(responseMessage.Binary);

        if (serverMsg.LogonResult != null)
        {
            _loginStateSubject.OnNext(LogonState.LoggedIn);
            await _pendingRequestsManager.TryInvokeFirstMatchingAsync<Logon>(serverMsg);
        }
        else if (serverMsg.RestoreOrJoinSessionResult != null)
        {
            await _pendingRequestsManager.TryInvokeFirstMatchingAsync<RestoreOrJoinSession>(serverMsg);
        }
        else if (serverMsg.LoggedOff != null)
        {
            _loginStateSubject.OnNext(LogonState.LoggedOff);
            await _pendingRequestsManager.TryInvokeFirstMatchingAsync<Logoff>(serverMsg);
        }
        else if (serverMsg.InformationReports.Count > 0)
        {
            await _pendingRequestsManager.TryInvokeAsync(serverMsg.InformationReports[0].Id, serverMsg);
        }
    }

    private Task DisconnectActionAsync(DisconnectionInfo info) => Task.CompletedTask;

    private async Task ReconnectActionAsync(ReconnectionInfo info)
    {
        _loginStateSubject.OnNext(LogonState.LoggedOff);

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(AuthenticateAsync(async onSuccess =>
            {
                var resultCodeName = Enum.GetName(typeof(LogonResult.Types.ResultCode), (LogonResult.Types.ResultCode)onSuccess.LogonResult.ResultCode) ?? "Unknown";

                switch (onSuccess.LogonResult.ResultCode)
                {
                    await _api.GetAccountInformationAsync(serverMsg =>
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Account information received. {Info}", serverMsg.InformationReports);
                        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    _ =>
                    {
                        _logger.LogInformation("Couldn't receive account information.");
                        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
                    });
                }
            }, onError =>
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("OnError = {OnError}", onError);
                return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}

public sealed class WebSocketCommunicator : WebsocketClient
{
    public WebSocketCommunicator(Uri url, Func<ClientWebSocket>? clientFactory = null) : base(url, clientFactory)
    {
    }

    public WebSocketCommunicator(Uri url,
        int reconnectTimeInSeconds,
        Func<DisconnectionInfo, Task> disconnect,
        Func<ReconnectionInfo, Task> reconnect,
        Func<ClientWebSocket>? clientFactory = null) : base(url, clientFactory)
    {
        ReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        ErrorReconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(reconnectTimeInSeconds);

        DisconnectionHappened.SubscribeAsync(disconnect);
        ReconnectionHappened.SubscribeAsync(reconnect);
    }
}

public class CqgApi
{
    private readonly CqgHostService _client;

    public CqgApi(CqgHostService client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task LogonAsync(string username, string password, string privateLabel, string clientAppId, string clientAppVersion,
        Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        var logon = new Logon
        {
            UserName = username,
            Password = password,
            PrivateLabel = privateLabel,
            ClientAppId = clientAppId,
            ClientVersion = clientAppVersion,
            SessionSettings = { (uint)Logon.Types.SessionSetting.AllowSessionRestore },
            ProtocolVersionMinor = Convert.ToUInt32(ProtocolVersionMinor.ProtocolVersionMinor),
            ProtocolVersionMajor = Convert.ToUInt32(ProtocolVersionMajor.ProtocolVersionMajor),
            DropConcurrentSession = false
        };

        await _client.RequestAsync(new ClientMsg { Logon = logon }, onSuccess, onError);
    }

    public async Task LogoffAsync(Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        var logoff = new Logoff();
        await _client.RequestAsync(new ClientMsg { Logoff = logoff }, onSuccess, onError);
    }

    public async Task GetAccountInformationAsync(Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError)
    {
        var informationRequest = new InformationRequest
        {
            Id = (uint)_client.GetNextRequestId(),
            AccountsRequest = new AccountsRequest()
        };

        await _client.RequestAsync(new ClientMsg { InformationRequests = { informationRequest } }, onSuccess, onError);
    }
}

public static class ObservableExtensions
{
     public static IDisposable SubscribeAsync<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, Task> onNext) =>
        source
            .Select(item => Observable.FromAsync(() => onNext(item)))
            .Merge() // executes concurrently
            .Subscribe();
}

public class PendingRequestManager
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, (Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> OnSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> OnError, IDisposable TimerSubscription)> _pendingRequests = new();

    public void Add(object request, Func<ServerMsg, ValueTask> onSuccess, Func<string, ValueTask> onError, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
    {
        var timerSubscription = Observable.Timer(requestTimeout)
            .SubscribeAsync(async _ =>
            {
                if (_pendingRequests.TryRemove(request, out var valueTuple))
                {
                    await valueTuple.OnError("Request timed out");
                    valueTuple.TimerSubscription.Dispose();
                }
            });

        _pendingRequests[request] = (onSuccess, onError, timerSubscription);
    }

    public async Task<bool> TryInvokeFirstMatchingAsync<TRequest>(ServerMsg serverMsg) where TRequest : class
    {
        foreach (var kvp in _pendingRequests)
        {
            if (kvp.Key.GetType().GetProperty(typeof(TRequest).Name) != null)
            {
                if (_pendingRequests.TryRemove(kvp.Key, out var tuple))
                {
                    await tuple.OnSuccess(serverMsg);
                    tuple.TimerSubscription.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public async Task<bool> TryInvokeAsync(object request, ServerMsg serverMsg)
    {
        if (_pendingRequests.TryRemove(request, out var tuple))
        {
            await tuple.OnSuccess(serverMsg);
            tuple.TimerSubscription.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```